# Async telnet connection over StreamSocket

Tags: c#, asynchronous

My team and I have a very poor understanding of best practices in relation to telnet. We have `Task.Delay` and `Task.Wait` in the code, including `async` voids and from what I understand those are potential areas that can cause deadlocks and other issues.

I'm trying to understand `async` in relation to running a telnet client. Is this a safe implementation of cancellation tokens and telnet connections?

```
public enum TelnetClientStatus : int
{
    Unset = 0,
    Connected= 1,
    Disconnected  = 2,
    Failed = 3
}

public TelnetClientStatus Status { get; set; } = TelnetClientStatus.Unset;

public async Task OpenConnection()
{
    //Don't allow the session to keep trying to open after the 5 seconds
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Status = await Task.Run(MakeConnection, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

private async Task<TelnetClientStatus> MakeConnection()
{
    _streamSocket = new StreamSocket();

    _dataWriter = new DataWriter(_streamSocket.OutputStream);
    _dataReader = new DataReader(_streamSocket.InputStream)
    {
        InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial
    };

    try
    {
        await _streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(HostName), Port.ToString());
        return TelnetClientStatus.Connected;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) //All other exceptions need to be investigated not ignored
    {
        //I understand a connection failed due to timeout, give the app some flag to work with
        //Maybe retry the connection?
        return TelnetClientStatus.Failed;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see at least two points.

- if you have a `catch` to catch a sytem `Exception` (wich is not good btw., it would be better to catch specific exceptions) and the only action is to `throw` that exception then its useless to have. If you need to rethrow an exception you should always omit the `ex` so just `throw;`, otherwise the `StackTrace` will be broken.
- Having the `public` setter of the `Status` property is breaking encapsulation. Why should a user of the object be able to set this property? You should make it `private`.

Comment: Unfortunately the exception that gets thrown is actually of type system exception and I have no way of being more specific.

Comment: @CBauer - Then don't catch it.  If you can't handle an exception, don't try.

Comment: @Bobson What do you mean? The exception is a generic async error of type `System.Exception` and occurs when one async call returns before a previous call due to network latency. The right thing to do in that situation is to ignore the response from the earlier call.

Comment: @CBauer - If the right thing to do is ignore it, then you should swallow the error with a comment explaining why (like you do with `TaskCanceledException`).  You don't *have* to catch `Exception` as the last thing in your `try/catch` block. Either do something with it or don't catch it.  Never just catch and rethrow without a very specific reason.

Comment: Wires crossed my mistake I was thinking of different code! I have removed the errant catch from the code.